# Thread await and execute different methods based on some event or value

Tags: multithreading, kotlin

Use case:

I am writing a proactive session updater; The use case is for parallel API calls or sequential API calls intercept the API call and check whether token is valid.

If token is valid continue with call
If token is invalid first update the token then continue with API call.

This is a cakewalk for sequential calls however for parallel calls I want to avoid DDOSing my server for repeated token calls.

Instead I have the following flow:

Suppose a burst of five parallel calls is intercepted by my token updater
The first call (Thread) goes to update the token, all the other four will await till token is updated by the first call. Once the token is updated, other threads continue with normal execution hence skipping the token updation.

Another point here is that requests might appear in bursts 5 API calls at T=1 and 10 API calls at some T=2 so I am also interested in resetting values 
(as in executionLatch)

Now the code I have for implementing this is loaded with frameworks and Jargon, instead for simplicity sake I have come up with a below skeleton of exceution:

```
class SingleUpdater {

    private val lock = ReentrantLock()
    private val executionLatch = AtomicBoolean(false)

    // Say valueToBeUpdated is my session token 
    private val valueToBeUpdated = AtomicInteger(0)

    private val awaitingThreadsCounter = AtomicInteger(0)


    fun start() {
        for (i in 0 until 100) {
            Thread(this::execute).start()
            Thread(this::execute).start()
            Thread(this::execute).start()
        }

        Thread.sleep(3000)

        for (i in 0 until 1) {
            Thread(this::execute).start()
            Thread(this::execute).start()
            Thread(this::execute).start()
        }

    }


    private fun execute() {

        println("Trying to acquire lock ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
        try {
            awaitingThreadsCounter.set(awaitingThreadsCounter.get() + 1)
            println("============================= awaitingThreadsCounter = ${awaitingThreadsCounter.get()} ============================= ")
            lock.lock()
            println("I am Thread ${Thread.currentThread().name} I have acquired lock")
            if (executionLatch.get()) {
                continueWithRestOfExecution()
            } else {
                doUpdate()
                continueWithRestOfExecution()
            }

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()

        } finally {
            println("Released by ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
            lock.unlock()

        }

    }

    private fun continueWithRestOfExecution() {
        if (awaitingThreadsCounter.get() >= 0) awaitingThreadsCounter.set(awaitingThreadsCounter.get() - 1)
        println("I am Thread: ${Thread.currentThread().name} and I am executing continueWithRestOfExecution")
        if (awaitingThreadsCounter.get() == 0) {
            println(" =============================  BALANCED  ============================= ")
            executionLatch.set(false)
        }
    }


    private fun doUpdate() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000)
            valueToBeUpdated.set(valueToBeUpdated.get() + 1)
            println("=============================== Value is: $valueToBeUpdated ${Thread.currentThread().name} ===============================")
            executionLatch.set(true)
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            ex.printStackTrace()
        }
    }


}
```

Please help in analysing edge cases here.